Why does script_proc.kill() in one thread not cause script_proc.wait() in a different thread to return?
I have a Tk GUI with start and cancel buttons.
The start button runs a thread that spawns a subprocess and waits for the response in order to update the GUI.
The cancel button kills the spawned subprocess.
The thread hangs when I try to join.  I'm not sure why the join call waits indefinitely as the subprocess is killed and it's exit value is available.
The documentation at (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) is not great - I know it says 'waits for a process to terminate', but the script uses a utility that seems to catch and ignore this, so I need to use kill.  I know the following code is simplified, but I do kill all child processes of the spawned script process.
If anyone knows what I've done wrong, or what I'm not doing, please let me know
class MyGUIClass

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_worker = MyWorkerClass()

    def on_start_button():
        self.worker_thread=Thread(target=self.start_process)
        self.worker_thread.start()

    def start_process(self):
        result = self.my_worker.run_script()        
        self.update_gui(result)     # Only gets here if not cancelled

    def on_cancel_button():
        self.my_worker.stop_script()
        self.worker_thread.join()   # Seems to hang here
        print('Never happens')

    def update_gui(self, result):
        # do something pretty


class MyWorkerClass

    def run_script(self):
        self.script_proc = subprocess.Popen(['script-to-be-run.bat'])
        self.script_proc.wait()
        return(self.script_proc.returncode == 0)

    def stop_script(self):
        self.script_proc.kill()
        print(f'PID {self.script_proc.pid} returned {self.script_proc.returncode}')

